# create an xpath expression in java that is to be filled in at runtime

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Assuming *blah* url has the following xml, I want to write an xpath expression (or if you have other ideas to implement this), that  outputs "**graphics**" when the value "**apple**" is supplied as a command line argument, or it outputs **QA** when **pfizer** is given as a command line argument. Also I would not have node names for this specific xml

```
<employers>
        <company-name>apple</company-name>
        <department>graphics</department>

        <company-name>pfizer</company-name>
        <department>QA</department>
</employers>
```

here is my attempt so far. please feel free to add additional code

```
 public class Xpathparser{
    public String parsing(){
    String url="http://www.blahurl.com";
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());
            XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(<xpathexpression?>);
            String neededValue=expr.evaluate(expr); //not sure about this.
    // code needed to display this
    System.out.println(doc.toString());
   }}
```

Comment: I am certain that you do not what to do this: `expr.evaluate(expr)`. You need to provide the document to the expression as an `InputSource`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a Java String variable assigned a company name,

```
String companyName = "apple";
```

You can construct an XPath expression,

```
"//department[preceding-sibling::company-name = '" + companyName + "'][1]"
```

That will select the `department` whose immediately previous sibling has a `company-name` given by the value of `companyName` (assuming that your accompanying Java `Document*` and `XPath*` facilities are correct).